# ¿Cómo crear un json con PHP con array dentro de array?

Tags: php, json, array

quiero crear un json con PHP y debe quedar así:

```
{
  "requisito": [
    {
      "nombre": "Pedro",
      "apellido": "Herrera",
      "fec_nac": "28/06/2000"
    },
    {
      "nombre": "Julia",
      "apellido": "Sucre",
      "fec_nac": "08/01/1998"
    }
  ]
}
```

Nota: con llaves, corchetes y fechas así como están.

Este es mi código:

```
$requisito[]=array("nombre" => "Pedro", "apellido" => "Herrera", "fec_nac" => 

"28/06/2000");
$requisito[]=array("nombre" => "Maria", "apellido" => "Sucre", "fec_nac" => 

"08/01/1998");  

echo json_encode($requisito,true);
```

Y la salida es:

```
[{"nombre":"Pedro","apellido":"Herrera","fec_nac":"28\/06\/2000"},

{"nombre":"Maria","apellido":"Sucre","fec_nac":"08\/01\/1998"}]
```

Por favor, qué debo hacer para que:

1) Comience con llaves {

2) "requisito":

3)  Y en las fechas no coloque esa barra invertida.

Gracias de antemano!

Comment: ¿Podrías decir de dónde vienen los datos o por qué debes crearlos manualmente?  Se podría convertir la misma cadena a JSON con `json_decode` o bien a partir del array crear el JSON con `json_encode`... lo que no entiendo es de dónde salen los datos ¿?

Comment: Saludos, vienen de un formulario, pero en realidad lo quise presentar así para resumir el código. Pero ya lo solucioné.

Comment: Hice esto: $data=array ("requisito" => $requiere);
echo json_encode($data,true); Es decir, array dentro de array.  Fue un "lapsus brutus" que tuve. Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 2):

La forma de crear el array sería esta:

```
$arr=array(
            "requisito"=>
            array(
                    array("nombre"=>"Pedro", "apellido"=>"Herrera", "fec_nac"=>"28/06/2000"),
                    array("nombre"=>"Julia", "apellido"=>"Sucre",    "fec_nac"=>"08/01/1998")
                  )
        );
```

Y para evitar que escape los caracteres `/` de la fecha, le puedes pasar [**`JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES`**](http://php.net/manual/es/json.constants.php) a [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.json-encode.php):

```
$json=json_encode($arr,JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
echo $json;
```

Salida:

```
{
    "requisito": [{
        "nombre": "Pedro",
        "apellido": "Herrera",
        "fec_nac": "28/06/2000"
    }, {
        "nombre": "Julia",
        "apellido": "Sucre",
        "fec_nac": "08/01/1998"
    }]
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!

Comment: @decoro se me escapó una anidación en el código PHP, lo he corregido en la edición.

Answer (score 2):

Ya teniendo el arreglo $requisito lleno puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
echo json_encode(['requisito' => $requisito], true);
//Incluso puedes simplificarlo con la función compact de php de esta manera
// echo json_encode(compact('requisito'), true);
```

Y te saldra como deseas :P

El key del problema es que querias devolver el json como un object donde la clave `requisito` fuera el ke contuviera el arreglo, por tanto al pasar un arreglo con la llave `'requisito'` en php y su valor es el arreglo original, se te formará el json tal y cual esperas.